# Installing Zend Framework 2 in WAMP - localhost points to the same root as my Zend project

Tags: zend-framework2

I am trying to learn about the Zend Framework and this is frustrating cause I can't even get to install the darn thing. :) So please help.

OP: Windows 7
Server: WAMP

I fould allot of documentation for Zend Framework 1 but not version 2 (which is the one I want).

Let me tell you what I did and what's the problem.

1. I have installed a working WAMP server, accessed from `http://localhost`
2. In the wamp's www, I have made a folder called "zendy" for the framework
3. I went to windows, system 32, drivers, etc and edited my host file. Here I have:
   127.0.0.1       localhost
   127.0.0.1       zendy   # I have added this for my zend project
4. Then I went to httpd.conf and added this at the end:

   ServerName zendy
       DocumentRoot "C:\wamp\www\zendy"
5. I went to the Zend Framework 2 docs and downloaded the zend skeleton, pasted the contend inside my zendy folder. From the command line I typed:

   "php composer.phar self-update"
       "php composer.phar install"

Just like the zend [framework 2 doc](http://framework.zend.com/manual/2.0/en/user-guide/skeleton-application.html) says.

The install worked ok and I saw this:

```
Installing dependencies from lock file
- Installing zendframework/zendframework (dev-master)
  Cloning 18c8e223f070deb07c17543ed938b54542aa0ed8

Generating autoload files
```

1. Now, if I type `http://zendy` everything works ok but if I type `http://localhost`, I get the same zendy directory and I have lost access to my other php projects (non zend) which were in the www folder.

**So basically: `http://localhost` goes to the same place as `http://zendy` (I have lost access to my localhost).**

Any ideas on what is wrong?

Comment: google for apache virtualhost http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/vhosts/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add your localhost as well as your other projects to the virtual hosts file.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  DocumentRoot "C:\serverpath\htdocs"
  ServerName localhost
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: nice ans., and 
can we use ServerName "localhost" in this ?